# Updating kernel in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, kernel-module, uname

I am trying to update my kernel for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from 3.4.0 to the newest version available, but `uname -r` continues to return `3.4.0` no matter what I do. I have also tried to reboot my system multiple times, to no avail.

The output of `sudo update-grub` is as follows:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found unknown Linux distribution on /dev/sda3
Found unknown Linux distribution on /dev/sda5
Found Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sda7
done
```

It would be great if anyone knew how to update/upgrade to the newest kernel.
[When I say update, I'm not entirely sure what that entails, but I'm trying to install the headers, the image, and especially, build the modules (because I believe that VirtualBox won't run on my system because of some sort of module issue)].

As a heads up, I have done many a google search to try to find the answer, so my attempts to solve this problem have extremely varied, but my working knowledge of the whole idea of kernels (and updating them) and what comprises them, is fairly limited.

I would be more than happy to run any commands in terminal if necessary, and if you do come across an answer, please keep in mind that I'm a kernel 'newby' of sorts, so detailed explanation and steps, or link(s) thereto are extremely appreciated.

As a final note, I am running 32-bit ChrUbuntu installed by Jay Lee's script (just fyi, the unknown Linux distros on /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda5 are ChromeOS [the default OS for my chromebook]), which may or may not have anything to do with this issue, but I'm no expert, so any insight would be cool, but is by no means necessary.

**EDIT**: The contents of /boot/grub/grub.conf  are as follows:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro   crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-19-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro   crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro   crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro   crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-34-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro   crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.38-8-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda3)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
}
menuentry "unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda3)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
}
menuentry "unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda3)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0 root=/dev/sda3
}
menuentry "unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda5)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5
}
menuentry "unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda5)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5
}
menuentry "unknown Linux distribution (on /dev/sda5)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0 root=/dev/sda5
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic-pae (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-34-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda7)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=UUID=48ba90b7-e174-4460-9b09-308e40541728 ro recovery nomodeset
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Answer (score 0):

from output of `update-grub` it would seem that kernel 3.5.0-19 is successfully installed

are you presented with grub menu on boot? what are the choices there?

might want to `sudo grub-set-default X` to set default boot entry, check in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which entry is the 3.5.0-19 and set `X` accordingly (probably will be 0)

Comment: I do NOT get a grub menu on boot, and `uname -r` still returns/displays `3.4.0`

Comment: can you post contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Comment: Yes, it is now in the post.

Comment: ok, nothing unusual there, maybe try to get that grub menu, either hit/hold shift during boot (timing might be tricky) or edit `/etc/default/grub`, comment out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=x` and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: when I update my kernel, grub didn't setup correctly (it asked me which drives to install grub on, but then none of the drives worked), and trying to hold shift at boot doesn't seem to work either, and I don't think it [ever] will.